# I am confused with my knowledge of polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, functional-equations

Is $x^2+cos(x)=0$ a polynomial?

Please help( I know its a naive question)

Comment: See [Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial): "In mathematics, a polynomial is an expression consisting of variables (or indeterminates) and coefficients, that involves only the operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and non-negative integer exponents of variables. "

Comment: Nope, $\cos(x)$ isn't, so adding it to a polynomial ($x^2$ is one) makes that not a polynomial. Furthermore, the $=0$ makes it an equality rather than an expression, and I'd say polynomials usually refer to expressions

Comment: You should have some definition of a polynomial handy. Then you can check if this function fits in.

Comment: And please learn to use $\LaTeX$ from https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

It is not. If it were, then
$$\cos(x) = x^2 + \cos(x) - x^2$$ whould be a polynomial as well, bus $\cos(x)$ has too many zeros ( infinite). A (non-zero) polynomial can only have a finite number of zeros.

Answer (score 1):

No, for two reasons:

1. If $f(x)= x^2 + \cos(x) $ were a polynomial, then some derivative of $f$ would be identically zero, but $f^{(n)}(x)=\pm \cos(x)$ or $\pm \sin(x)$ for $n>2$.
2. If $f(x)= x^2 + \cos(x) $ were a polynomial, then so would $\cos(x)$, but $\cos(x)$ is a bounded nonconstant function and the only bounded polynomials are the constant functions.

Answer (score -1):

It's not! Only powers of $x$ can appear in a polynomial, no trig functions. Also, technically, a polynomial is an expression not an equality.

Comment: Is that like $x$ must be free of any other functions?

Comment: Well, if we're really going to nitpick, trig functions could appear; for example, $\cos(x)^2+\sin(x)^2$ is a polynomial